# How do I get the shader node type in python?

Tags: python

If I do:

```
print(some_node.type)
```

I get things such as `MIX_SHADER`

but if I do:

```
print(some_node)
```

I get

```
<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeMixShader("Mix Shader.001") at 0x7fdb7da7f808>
```

Barring the use of regexes, is there a way to get the type of the `bpy_struct` - in other words `ShaderNodeMixShader`?

so I can use it for templating code later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> node.bl_idname
'ShaderNodeMixShader'
```

Alternatively, you can use the same way you get the name of anything's type in Python

```
>>> type(node)
<class 'bpy.types.ShaderNodeMixShader'>

>>> type(node).__name__
'ShaderNodeMixShader'
```